# uniqueness in XML document using xsd schema

Tags: xml, validation, schema, unique-constraint

I'm strugglying with the following use case in XML validation using XSD.

Please consider the following piece of XML

```
<Library>
  <Book>Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?</Book>
  <Book>Choke</Book>
  <Book>Choke</Book>
</Library>
```

How would you write the XSD that avoid a book being duplicated?

So that xml above won't pass the validation.

I'm able to guarantee uniqueness if a book contains a subelement like "title".

Thanks in advance
Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple to implement by using `xs:key` construct. Check it out.

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Library xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="LibraryNew.xsd">
    <Book>Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?</Book>
    <Book>Choke</Book>
    <Book>Choke</Book>
</Library>
```

> XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Library">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Book"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <!-- Primary Key -->
        <xs:key name="PK">
            <xs:selector xpath="Book"/>
            <xs:field xpath="."/>
        </xs:key>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Book" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks you very much for your hint. Actually the very important part is ***<xs:field xpath="."/>***. The xs:unique still usable. I need to improve the knowledge of xpath :).